# Using if statements to build a PDO MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am attempting to use PDO to retrieve rows from a MySQL database, but want to be able to filter/search the results. Therefore, I have created a function and am using variables that contain the filter/search options.

Here is my code so far:

```
function getbycategory($category, $search){
    global $db;
    $base_query = "SELECT * FROM parts ";
    $category = "WHERE main_category = :category ";
    $search = "WHERE name LIKE :search ";

    if (isset($category)){
        $query = $base_query.$category;
        if (isset($search)){
            $query = $base_query.$category.$search;
        }
    }

    if (!isset($category)){
        $query = $base_query;
        if (isset($search)){
            $query = $base_query.$search;
        }
    }

    $sm = $db->prepare ($query);
    if (isset($category)){
        $sm->bindParam(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
    if (isset($search)){
        $sm->bindParam(':search', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }

    $sm->execute();
    return $sm->fetchAll();
}
```

I am then using the following to call the function:

```
$files = getbycategory($_GET['filter'], $_GET['search']);
```

And the search/filter are defined by the following:

```
<form method="get">
<select name="filter">
    <option <?php if($_GET['filter'] == "all" OR !isset($_GET['filter'])){echo 'selected';} ?> value="all">View All Files</option>
    <option <?php if($_GET['filter'] == "1") {echo 'selected';} ?> value="1">View Vehicles Only</option>
    <option <?php if($_GET['filter'] == "2") {echo 'selected';} ?> value="2">View Lighting Equiptment</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Filter Results"/><br /><br />
<input type="text" name="search" <?php if(isset($_GET['search'])){echo 'value="'.$_GET['search'].'"';}?> placeholder="Enter a search term" />
<input type="submit" value="Search Results"/>
</form>
```

The results are then looped using:

```
foreach($files as $file){

echo'<div class="col-lg-" id="file-'.$file['id'].'">
        <div class="file-list-item first" id="">
            <img class="file-image" height="120px" width="180px" src="'.$file['image_url'].'" />
            <div class="file-text">
                <h3><strong>'.$file['name'].'</strong></h3>
                Submitted by: '.$file['submitter'].'<br/>
                Author: '.$file['author'].'<br />
                Category: '.ucfirst($file['subcategory']).'<br />
                Description: '.substr($file['description'],0,45).'...
            </div>
            <div class="download">
                <a target="_blank" href="'.$file['download_url'].'" class="btn-success btn btn-default">Download</a>
                <a href="'.baseurl.'/broken.php?id='.$file['id'].'" class="btn btn-default">Report as Broken</a><br /><br />';
                    if($file['is_broken']){
                        echo '<span class="broken"><i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" id="broken" title="This file has been reported as broken and is awaiting review." class="fa fa-warning fa-2x"></i></span>';
                    }


                echo '

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
};
```

However, my code is not working and no results are being displayed. Can anyone offer any advice?

Many thanks.

---

**UPDATE**
I have updated the function to resolve the problem highlighted by Dave.

```
function getbycategory($category, $search){
    global $db;
    $base_query = "SELECT * FROM parts ";
    $category = "WHERE main_category = :category ";
    $search = " name LIKE :search ";

    if (isset($category)){
        $query = $base_query.$category;
        if (isset($search)){
            $query = $base_query.$category.'AND'.$search;
        }
    }

    if (!isset($category)){
        $query = $base_query;
        if (isset($search)){
            $query = $base_query.'WHERE'.$search;
        }
    }

    $sm = $db->prepare ($query);
    if (isset($category)){
        $sm->bindParam(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
    if (isset($search)){
        $sm->bindParam(':search', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }

    $sm->execute();
    return $sm->fetchAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be other issues, but the one I noticed is that the query generated here:

```
$base_query = "SELECT * FROM parts ";
$category = "WHERE main_category = :category ";
$search = "WHERE name LIKE :search ";

if (isset($category)){
    $query = $base_query.$category;
    if (isset($search)){
        $query = $base_query.$category.$search;
    }
}
```

When you have both `$category` and `$search`, is:

```
SELECT * FROM parts WHERE main_category = :category WHERE name LIKE :search
```

which isn't valid, it would need to be:

```
SELECT * FROM parts WHERE main_category = :category AND name LIKE :search
```

EDIT:

Found the other issue:

You pass in `$category` and `$search`:

```
getbycategory($category, $search){
```

Then you overwrite them:

```
     $category = "WHERE main_category = :category ";
     $search = " name LIKE :search ";
```

Then you bind them:

```
$sm->bindParam(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sm->bindParam(':search', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

So you get a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM parts 
WHERE main_category =  "WHERE main_category = :category " 
AND name LIKE " name LIKE :search "
```

And for your like, when you get to it, you need to add the `%` to the variable to do wildcard matching:

```
$sm->bindParam(':search', '%' . $search . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. I have added an updated version of the function. Does this look any better?

Comment: Looks better - does the page load all the way just no data?  Or does it stop rendering at some point? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: The page loads just fine, but no data is displayed. I had it working with a more basic function without the search, just the category so I know there's nothing wrong with the database etc..  Also, there are no errors whatsoever in apache's logs.